# Serve files from storage in Laravel (symlink custom storage path)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I want to create a video sharing site for a spacific niche (mini-youtube kind of thing).

I have created the upload functionality successfully, and files are stored in `storage/public/videos`

I then created a symlink using `php artisan storage:link`

When I try to access the files using `echo asset('storage/videos/file.mp4');` as  stated at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem

my html in the view looks like

```
<video controls>

<source src="{{ asset('storage/videos/file.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

**QUESTION** : What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Should be `asset('storage/videos/file.mp4')`?

Comment: SOrry, that's what I meant but it still doesn't fix the problem at all. I just get a 404

Comment: can You do: `ls -la public` ?

Comment: It  gives me a whole bunch of symlinks :
`public -> storage/app/public` 
and 
`storage -> PATH/storage/app/public`

Comment: So as You see non of that symlinks refer to Your publicly accessible folder. So check my answer and add Your custom symlink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#configuration):

> The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly
>   accessible. By default, the  public disk uses the local driver and
>   stores these files in **storage/app/public**. To make them accessible from
>   the web, you should create a symbolic link from **public/storage** to 
>   **storage/app/public**. This convention will keep your publicly accessible
>   files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments
>   when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.

as You understand when You do `php artisan storage:link` it does following:

```
ln -s storage/app/public public/storage
```

but You're keeping Your files in `storage/public/videos` that is not accessible (being linked) by documentation.

2 solutions:

1) You've to manually do (manually create symlinks):

```
ln -s storage/public/videos public/storage/videos
```

and in code to use it like: `asset('storage/videos/file.mp4')`

2) Change file storage methods to store files by convention: `storage/app/public/videos`

Comment: You were right. It was the way the symlink was done. Thanks

Comment: As a note, for those who has been created another separate custom disk, you should give the absolute path of the folders like: `ln -s /home/vagrant/ams/storage/app/files /home/vagrant/ams/public/files`